# Alinhar texto no menu navbar do Bootstrap

Tags: html5, css3, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Olá, não estou conseguindo alinhar na direita os textos clicáveis do meu menu com Bootstrap.

Aqui está o código do menu em HTML:

```html
 <span class="menuresponsivo">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light bg-transparent">
   <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
   </button>
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
     <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#" style="color:white; ">Sobre nós</a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#" style="color:white; ">Serviços</a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#" style="color:white; ">Contato</a>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </nav>
 </span>
```

Aqui está o css da tag span que criei, essa tag foi criada pra definir fontes, margens, etc:

```css
.menuresponsivo{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  margin-top: 1%;
  margin-right: 2%;
  
}
```

E meu menu está como na imagem abaixo, o que eu quero é mudar o "Sobre Nós", "Serviços", e o "Contato" para a direita.
Já tentei usar o *text-align: right;* mas não vai.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara vc pode alinhar esse elementos a direita simplesmente colocando um `margin-left:auto;`, para isso use a classe nativa do BS `ml-auto`

Eu coloquei um fundo vermelho só para ficar mais fácil de visualizar, mas vc pode colocar o style que quiser.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código da imagem acima

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Page Title</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.8.2/css/all.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<style>
  .menuresponsivo {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    margin-top: 1%;
    margin-right: 2%;

  }
</style>
</head>

<body>

  <header class="menuresponsivo">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light  bg-danger">
      <button class="navbar-toggler ml-auto" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse ml-auto" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item ml-auto">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#" style="color:white; ">Sobre nós</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item ml-auto">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#" style="color:white; ">Serviços</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item ml-auto">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#" style="color:white; ">Contato</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

se você acessar a página do [w3shools > bootstrap > navbar](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_navbar.asp), você encontrará um exemplo que, ao acrescentar a classe "navbar right", a navegação ficará alinhada à direita conforme desejado!

```
class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right"
```

Comment: Testei adicionando o navbar-right em cada class do menu, uma por uma, e não funcionou.

Comment: Fala Igor, fiquei um pouco intrigado por não ter funcionado daí salvei o teste no [codepen](https://codepen.io/limasq/pen/oNNMLag) e utilizando Bootstrap 3.3.7. Não era isso que tu queria? Veja a class da tag "ul" `<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">`